# iOS Compilation ERROR (built with Unity)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand why my code is not working, and between having very little knowledge of iOS languages and the code/files being written from Unity, I am unable to break down these errors. All help is extremely appreciated.

```
  "_UnityADBannerViewFailedToLoad", referenced from:

  "_UnityADBannerViewWasClicked", referenced from:

  "_UnityADBannerViewWasLoaded", referenced from:

  "_UnityADInterstitialADWasLoaded", referenced from:

  "_UnityADInterstitialADWasViewed", referenced from:

  "_UnityBindFramebuffer", referenced from:

  "_UnityBlitToBackbuffer", referenced from:

  "_UnityCaptureScreenshot", referenced from:

  "_UnityCleanup", referenced from:

  "_UnityCreateDummySurface", referenced from:

  "_UnityCreateExternalSurfaceGLES", referenced from:

  "_UnityDeliverUIEvents", referenced from:

  "_UnityDestroyExternalSurface", referenced from:

  "_UnityDidAccelerate", referenced from:

  "_UnityDidCaptureVideoFrame", referenced from:

  "_UnityDisableDepthAndStencilBuffers", referenced from:

  "_UnityDisableRenderBuffers", referenced from:

  "_UnityDropViewTouchProcessing", referenced from:

  "_UnityEndFrame", referenced from:

  "_UnityFinishRendering", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetAccelerometerFrequency", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetAppBackgroundBehavior", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetDataContextGLES", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetDesiredMSAASampleCount", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetLaunchScreenXib", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetRenderingAPIs", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetRenderingResolution", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetSRGBRequested", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetShowActivityIndicatorOnLoading", referenced from:

  "_UnityGetTargetFPS", referenced from:

  "_UnityHasRenderingAPIExtension", referenced from:

  "_UnityInitApplicationGraphics", referenced from:

  "_UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics", referenced from:

  "_UnityInputProcess", referenced from:

  "_UnityIsCaptureScreenshotRequested", referenced from:

  "_UnityIsOrientationEnabled", referenced from:

  "_UnityIsPaused", referenced from:

  "_UnityLoadApplication", referenced from:

  "_UnityParseCommandLine", referenced from:

  "_UnityPause", referenced from:

  "_UnityPlayerLoop", referenced from:

  "_UnityRegisterFBO", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportAVCapturePermission", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportBackbufferChange", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportResizeView", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportWWWFinishedLoadingData", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportWWWReceivedData", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportWWWReceivedResponse", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportWWWSentData", referenced from:

  "_UnityReportWWWStatusError", referenced from:

  "_UnityRequestRenderingResolution", referenced from:

  "_UnityRequestedScreenOrientation", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendDeviceToken", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendLocalNotification", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendRemoteNotification", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendTouchesBegin", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendTouchesCancelled", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendTouchesEnded", referenced from:

  "_UnitySendTouchesMoved", referenced from:

  "_UnitySensorsSetAttitude", referenced from:

  "_UnitySensorsSetGravity", referenced from:

  "_UnitySensorsSetGyroRotationRate", referenced from:

  "_UnitySensorsSetGyroRotationRateUnbiased", referenced from:

  "_UnitySensorsSetUserAcceleration", referenced from:

  "_UnitySetJoystickPosition", referenced from:

  "_UnitySetKeyState", referenced from:

  "_UnitySetLogEntryHandler", referenced from:

  "_UnitySetPlayerFocus", referenced from:

  "_UnitySetViewTouchProcessing", referenced from:

  "_UnityShouldAutorotate", referenced from:

  "_UnityStartFrame", referenced from:

  "_UnityStringToKey", referenced from:

  "_UnityUpdateDisplayList", referenced from:

  "_UnityUseAnimatedAutorotation", referenced from:

  "_UnityWillPause", referenced from:

  "_UnityWillResume", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_ShowSpecificLeaderboardUI()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_LoadAchievementDescriptions()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_ShowDefaultAchievementBanner()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_UI()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Font()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Mesh()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Light()", referenced from:

  "UnitySetLastHeading(float, float, float, float, float, double)", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Camera()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Canvas()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Motion()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Shader()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Sprite()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_Audio()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_IMGUI()", referenced from:

  "UnitySetLastLocation(double, float, float, float, float, float)", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Cubemap()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GUIText()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Texture()", referenced from:

  "il2cpp_gc_alloc_fixed(unsigned long, void*)", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Animator()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Collider()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GUILayer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Material()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Renderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_Physics()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AudioClip()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Behaviour()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Component()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_TextAsset()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Texture2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Texture3D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Transform()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Collider2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_FlareLayer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GUIElement()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GameObject()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MeshFilter()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MonoScript()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_SampleClip()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_TagManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_Animation()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_Physics2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_BoxCollider()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_CanvasGroup()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GameManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MonoManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_NamedObject()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_NetworkView()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_PreloadData()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Rigidbody2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_TimeManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AudioManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_InputManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MeshCollider()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MeshRenderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_ScriptMapper()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AnimationClip()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AudioListener()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_BoxCollider2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_BuildSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MonoBehaviour()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_RectTransform()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_RenderTexture()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_TrailRenderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_UnityConnect()", referenced from:

  "il2cpp_array_addr_with_size(Il2CppArray*, int, unsigned long)", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AudioBehaviour()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_CanvasRenderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_DirectorPlayer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_EdgeCollider2D()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_NetworkManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_PhysicsManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_PlayerSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_RenderSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_SphereCollider()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_SpriteRenderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_TextRendering()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_EditorExtension()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_QualitySettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_ResourceManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GraphicsSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_LevelGameManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_LightmapSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_ParticleRenderer()", referenced from:

  "RegisterModule_ParticlesLegacy()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_GlobalGameManager()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_Physics2DSettings()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_PolygonCollider2D()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_Init()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_Clear()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_AnimatorController()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_DelayedCallManager()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_get_uv()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_get_uv2()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_UnityConnectSettings()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_Cleanup()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_GUIStyle_Init()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Gradient_Init()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Input_GetAxis()", referenced from:

  "RegisterClass_MasterServerInterface()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_PopEvent()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_get_type()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Input_GetTouch()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_Destroy()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Resources_Load()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Screen_get_dpi()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Camera_get_main()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_GUI_set_changed()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_GameObject_Find()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Input_GetKeyInt()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_GetIndices()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_ToString()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_get_name()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_set_name()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_RectOffset_Init()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Camera_get_depth()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_get_dynamic()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_GUIStyle_Cleanup()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Gradient_Cleanup()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Input_GetAxisRaw()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_get_normals()", referenced from:

  "Register_UnityEngine_Screen_get_width()", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to check player settings. If you want to run on simulator, set `Simulator SDK`, otherwise `Device SDK`.

[image]

It seems like you've set device SDK and are trying to run on simulator.

Comment: I am currently trying this, hold on. Thank you though for your answer and patience

Comment: Thank you Very Very much @Leo